# React DVA JS Framework: Reset entire state application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I'm using DVA JS Framework (https://github.com/dvajs/dva) in a React Project.
I have a login/logout feature in this web app.

**The problem:**
When I logout the state stays the same. I need to reset the entire state without refreshing the page.

Is there a way to do it in DVA Framework?

In DVA documentation (https://github.com/dvajs/dva/blob/master/docs/API.md) there are many ways to access different things in the app.

```
const app = dva({
  initialState,
  onAction,
  onStateChange,
  onReducer,
  onEffect,
});
```

Is there a way to reset the state inside these configurations?

Answer (score 1):

How are you logging out? Using dva you need to use the model to do that, in order to trigger an "effect" saga. You can then trigger a state change to reset the values you need. For example:

```
...
effects {
  *logout({ payload }, { call, put }) {
    const confirmation = yield call(logout, {});
    if (confirmation.success) {
      yield put({ type: 'resetToDefaults' });
    } else {
      throw (confirmation);
    }
  },
},
reducers {
  resetToDefaults(state) {
    return {
      ...state,
      //Modify your required entries to the default values
    };
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 state the first is my actual state, and second is defaultState that will execute when i call resetToDefaults.